Transform the type of an object
This is my entity:
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "dtype", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING, columnDefinition = "varchar(31) default 'RAW_QUOTATION'")
public class Quotations {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String description;
}

I want to extend all of its properties into the following:
@Getter
@Setter
public class SingleQuotationDto extends Quotations {
    private String receiverName;
}

In my service I have an object that has the type Quotations:
Optional<Quotations> quotation = quotationRepository.findById(id);
    quotation.ifPresent(quotations -> {
...
}

I want to transform the type of this object into SingleQuotationDto, so that I can set receiverName to it.
I know that I can do:
SingleQuotationDto singleQuotationDto = new SingleQuotationDto(quotations);
singleQuotationDto.setReceiverName("Receiver's Name");
singleQuotationDto.setDescription("description");

but quotations is already predefined. So I don't want to add each property manually.
Also, I consider it as a bad practice if I use setters for the entity. Since when I add new properties, I have to add their setters in this service as well. I am pretty sure there must be a cleaner solution.

Can't you just use a mapping library? There is plenty of those - ModelMapper, MapStruct, and so on, the list is pretty long.

Another strategy would be to extract an interface from class Quotations, let Quotations and the DTO implement that interface and use an instance of Quotations as delegate. This gives us the freedom to add new methods to SingleQuotationDto, while "forwarding" the old methods to the delegate.

The solution is the annotation @delegate (lombok.experimental.Delegate), together with @JsonIgnore (com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;) to avoid duplicated properties.
@Getter
@Setter
public class SingleQuotationDto {
    @Delegate
    @JsonIgnore
    private Quotations quotations;
    private String receiverName;
}

SingleQuotationDto singleQuotationDto = new SingleQuotationDto();
singleQuotationDto.setQuotations(quotations);
singleQuotationDto.setReceiverName("Receiver's Name");

